# Javascript Rock Paper Scissors

Tags: javascript, if-statement

why is my programme not working?

is there something wrong with my Math.random?

"Do you choose Rock, Paper or Scissors?"

"Do you choose Rock, Paper or Scissors?"

"Do you choose Rock, Paper or Scissors?"

//////////////////////////////

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose Rock, Paper or Scissors?")

var computerChoice = Math.random();

//======================================

if(computerChoice <= 0.33 )
{
    computerChoice = "Rock";
}

else if(computerChoice <= 0.66)
{
    computerChoice = "Paper";
}

else 
{
    computerChoice = "Scissors";
}

console.log("Computer: " + computerChoice);

//==========================================

var compare = function(choice1, choice2)
{
    if(choice1 === choice2)
    {
        return "The result is a tie!";
    }

    else if(choice1 === "Rock")
    {
        if(choice2 === "Scissors")  
        {
            return "Rock wins";
        }
        else
        {
            return "Paper wins";
        }
    }

    else if(choice1 === "Paper")
    {
        if(choice2 === "Rock")
        {
            return "Paper wins";
        }
        else
        {
            return "Scissors wins";
        }
    }

    else if(choice1 === "Scissors")
    {
        if(choice2 === "Paper")
        {
            return "Scissors wins";
        }
        else
        {
            return "Rock wins";
        }
    }
};

compare();
```

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `compare()` without any arguments. You need something like `compare(userChoice, computerChoice)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think overall your logic is way too complex.  If you simplify by making an associative array of the possible choices and the thing they beat, you can streamline a lot of your logic, like so:

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose Rock, Paper, or Scissors?");
userChoice = userChoice.toLowerCase();

var rules = {'rock': 'scissors', 'paper': 'rock', 'scissors': 'paper'};
var choices = Object.keys(rules);

var computerChoice = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];

// User entered an invalid option
if (choices.indexOf(userChoice) < 0) {
    console.log('You entered an invalid choice');
} else if (userChoice === computerChoice) {
  console.log('Tie!!');
} else {
  // now actually see who won
  var userBeats = rules[userChoice];
  if (userBeats === computerChoice) {
    console.log('User won with ' + userChoice + ' vs ' + computerChoice);
  } else {
     console.log('Computer won with ' + computerChoice + ' vs ' + userChoice);
  }
}
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9c5jv9zk/)

Of course, you can still separate things out into functions.

The other thing that makes it easy is that `Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)` will yield a number between 0 and 2 (inclusive), so you can use that to access the choice in the `choices` array and skip most of your assignment logic.